# [MSVC]encounter std::__non_rtti_object exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, rtti

In my case I write a `Kernel.dll` which wraps CxImage object(either CxImageJPG or CxImage) defined in `xImage.dll` which shared with other binary modules(no sourcecode):

```
class CCxImageWraper{
  public:
    shared_ptr<CxImage> m_spImage;
    ...
}
```

when I use a dynamic_cast it fails with `std::__non_rtti_object` exception:

```
m_spImage.reset(new CxImageJPG);  // always std::__non_rtti_object exception
CxImageJPG* cxJpgImage = dynamic_cast<CxImageJPG*>(m_spImage.get());
```

I'm sure that `kernal.dll` project use the option `/GR (Enable Run-Time Type Information)`, and the pointer `m_spImage.get()` here is not NULL and it is surely point to a `CxImageJPG` instatance. **Don't know why it throws std::__non_rtti_object Is any information I was missing?**

I did try create a new console project `Test.exe` and `TestDll.dll`, `Test.exe` always turn on `GR` switch,  `TestDll.dll` has two class: `BaseClass`, `SubClass`, whatever option I set to `TestDll.dll`: `/GR` or `/GR-`, `/MT` or `/MDd` or `/MTd`. Test.exe always can dynamic_cast the object defined in `TestDll.dll`:

```
boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass> spItem(new SubClass());
SubClass* pClass = dynamic_cast<SubClass*>(spItem.get());  // always no exception
```

Aready checked problem, but can't find more information to my problem:

- [When and why is an std::__non_rtti_object exception generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854864/when-and-why-is-an-std-non-rtti-object-exception-generated)
- [dynamic cast throws pointer is not std::__non_rtti_object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582874/dynamic-cast-throws-pointer-is-not-std-non-rtti-object)

Comment: If you don't have the source code for the dll that implements `CxImageJPG`, why do you think it has been compiled with RTTI?

Comment: @rogerrowland I didn't assume that it compiled with RTTI, which I don't know, I just build a dll, compiled without RTTI, and the class in the dll can be dynamic_cast, I don't know why